# Бинарный поиск (С#)

Tags: c#, алгоритм, поиск

Тренируюсь на алгоритме бинарного поиска, но следующий метод не всегда возвращает последние или первые элементы в массиве (в зависимости от количества элементов показывает отрицательный результат нахождения того или иного элемента из конца или начала списка). Как мне можно улучшить этот алгоритм? Пробовала различные вариации, этот вариант показался оптимальным, но что-то все же идет не так)

```
        public static int Bsearch(int[] m, int left, int right, int item)
    {
      if (right >= 1 && !(right <= left))
        {
            int found = left + (right - left) / 2;
            if (m[found] > item) return Bsearch(m, left, found - 1, item);
            else if (m[found] < item) return Bsearch(m, found + 1, right, item);
            else return m[found];

        }
        else return -1;
```

Например, забьем массив от 0 до 19 и прогоним с этим методом (искомое значение идет в параметр item), значения 3 и 17 он не найдет (т.е. метод вернет -1):

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] massive = new int[20];
        for (int i = 0; i<massive.Length; i++)
        {
            massive[i] = i;
        }
        int result = Bsearch(massive, 0, massive.Length, 3);
        Console.WriteLine("{0} has found", result);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: Примеры входных данных еще выложите, на которых не работает.

Comment: `if (right >= 1 &&` а если `left == right == 0` ?

Comment: @АндрейNOP добавила в вопрос уточнения

Comment: @tym32167 не помогло, к сожалению

Comment: Что не помогло? Я вам случай скинул, где ваш алгоритм не отработает.

Comment: @tym32167 оу, не так поняла сначала) да, этот момент я упустила

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как писал Джон Бентли, одна из основных ошибок при реализации бинарного поиска - ошибка в индексах на единицу (off by 1). Вот здесь правая граница right входит в диапазон поиска или нет? Судя по главному вызову с `massive.Length` - не входит, а судя по рекурсивным вызовам с `found - 1` - входит. Надо просто разобраться в принципе поиска, тщательно выверить шаги алгоритма и воспользоваться отладкой (пошаговым прохождением с контролем переменных), если что не так.

Если правая граница входит, то условие выхода с отрицательным результатом

```
if (left > right)
```

вызов

```
int result = Bsearch(massive, 0, massive.Length - 1, 3);
```

остальное можно не менять.

Comment: Попробовала сначала с условием, когда входит, изменила две строчки, как вы предложили - в этот раз не нашло ни одного числа, затем попробовала, когда граница не входит - с 0 по 19 (то есть по содержимому массива) все ищет, но если попробовать забить большее число (от 20 и дальше), то StackoverflowException по рекурсиям)

Comment: Да ну? https://ideone.com/Czm7mZ  Может быть, кое- кто опять не задумался, что значит фраза "условие выхода с отрицательным результатом"?

Comment: Не, я понимаю, что значит условие выхода с отриц. результатом) Просто вы в ответе здесь немного не так написали, как на Ideone, а я скопировала на автомате =) Здесь if (left > right) , а на Ideone  if (right >= left). Поправила у себя теперь тоже - все работает! Большое спасибо за ответ и разъяснение)

Comment: https://ideone.com/VHp1F6

Comment: ууу, все, я поняла, надо быть внимательнее и еще раз внимательнее, поспешила) еще раз спасибо!